Removing a certain number and identifying the number
Question:
On YouTube, sometimes users put a disclaimer on their video when they use a content that belongs to someone else in order to avoid problems.
It is worth to note, that the section number that they put is one less than a powerful number, a prime number, and the next year that is divisible by that number is exactly (n2) years from now.
What is the number?
Bonus question:

 What is the full version of disclaimer that they put in the video/description?


The number is:

 107


 A "powerful number" is a positive integer n such that for every prime number p dividing n, p2 also divides n. 
 107 is one less than 108 = [22 $\times$ 33].

 The prime factors of 108 are 2 and 3. Since, 22 = 4 and 32 = 9 divide 108, 108 is a powerful number. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number


 107 is also a prime number


 The year 2033 = [19 $\times$ 107] is 9 years from now (2024), and 9 is a perfect square [9 = 32]. 

 It is also the closest year after 2024 to be divisible by 107.

The Full Version of the disclaimer they put in the video/description is:

 Copyright Disclaimer Under Section 107 of the Act 1976


Nice find, and it's probably this other definition that you need in the second spoiler

Oh, thx. I'll change that
